# Where can I find Rav David Tzvi Hoffman's commentary?

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries

I have seen it alleged that Rav David Tzvi Hoffman disagrees with the Ramban's interpretation of Devarim 18:15, and would like to see details. Where can I find his commentary, so as to compare what he says and what Ramban says?

Answer (score 8):

Al HaTorah has a [Mikraot Gedolot](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Devarim/18.15#e0n6) which includes Rav David Tzvi Hoffman's commentary.

The specific disagreement is linked, and begins as follows:

> מקרבך מאחיך – לשון כפולה. הרמב״ן מפרש, שכוונת הכתוב לומר, שאין הנבואה שורה אלא בארץ ישראל; אבל נראה שפירוש זה דחוק הוא.

It seems that Rav David Tzvi Hoffman considers "from among you, from your brothers" to be doubled repetition (for decorative or emphatic purposes). While Ramban seems to take "from among you" as restricting to it to the Land of Israel, Rav Hoffman considers this to be farfetched.